# How to install graphics drivers (no additional drivers under software sources)?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, intel-graphics, software-sources

I am using ubuntu gnome remix 12.10 with ATI mobility radeon HD 4300 graphics card. Software sources do not show any additional drivers. How do I install the graphics drivers for my system?

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4300 Series]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open your Ubuntu OS connect it to internet and open 'Additional Drivers' application (via pressing the windows button and type this 'Additional drivers').....Then it shows available graphics drivers for your system.......You can have a chance to installing from there and the problem will be solved......That's it.....

Comment: Did you read the question? The 'additional drivers' do not show any drivers.

Comment: Once check your internet connection and try this.....Because I am already faced this problem and I get rid of this problem.....

Comment: Nope. Internet is working fine here. I wonder if my card is even supported. If not, will it show the legacy drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this, but there is application "Additional Drivers" under Ubuntu Software Center, so maybe you can try with it. Or you can search for drivers on the official web page (ATI, NVidia etc..) and read instruction how to install it.